# What would be a modeling scheme to best visually represent the flow of an ReactJs app

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux, uml, staruml

I learn React JavaScript and wanted to understand React better so I wanted to create a nice visual work flow of my ReactJs app and came across this [free StarUml modeling tool](https://github.com/staruml/staruml-gitbook)

Looking in the [Docs](https://github.com/staruml/staruml-gitbook/tree/master/working-with-uml-diagrams) I see one can choose from a variety of diagrams like:

[Activity Diagram](https://github.com/staruml/staruml-gitbook/blob/master/working-with-uml-diagrams/activity-diagram.md)
[Class Diagram](https://github.com/staruml/staruml-gitbook/blob/master/working-with-uml-diagrams/class-diagram.md)
[Communication Diagram](https://github.com/staruml/staruml-gitbook/blob/master/working-with-uml-diagrams/communication-diagram.md)
and 11 more Diagram types on that page like:

```
component-diagram.md   
composite-structure-diagram.md   
deployment-diagram.md   
information-flow-diagram.md   
interaction-overview-diagram.md   
object-diagram.md   
package-diagram.md   
profile-diagram.md   
sequence-diagram.md   
statechart-diagram.md     
timing-diagram.md   
use-case-diagram.md
```

Here's an [Activity Diagram](https://github.com/staruml/staruml-gitbook/blob/master/working-with-uml-diagrams/activity-diagram.md) I found when Google; Will this type of diagram be enough to represent a ReactJs app using Redux, Sagas, multiple reducers Stores and backend is Firestore

(I don't want to represent Redux Store State or Component State, only the outer communication)

Activity diagram:

[image]

Comment: I can only say that this is an invalid diagram. As to your question: it's just too broad and needs more focus.

Comment: @qwerty_so the question is what type of diagram among the 14 suggest is best for React

Comment: Well, simply spoken: that depends.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Advice on which UML diagram to choose for self service checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64089827/advice-on-which-uml-diagram-to-choose-for-self-service-checkout) - the staruml diagrams are UML diagrams, and there are a lot of similar questions about the most suitable UML diagram for purpose X,y, z.

Comment: but I want a diagram only for ReactJs code not x, y, z